# Desktop crash following 18.10 to 19.04 upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, crash

Following upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04 I find the desktop is unusable. Following login I note the following:

- No items show up in the Dash-to-Dock dock on the left side except for the  square with nine dots (task drawer?) Clicking on it does nothing.
- Moving the mouse cursor to the upper left corner does not bring up the overview.
- Clicking on the upper left corner takes me back to the login screen.

This works for all logins I have tried:

- Gnome
- Gnome on Xorg
- Ubuntu on Xorg

I suppose some configuration item or shell extension is causing this. Before the upgrade I fully updated 18.10 but I have shell extensions installed through extensions.gnome.org and did not think to check them for updates. (The software manager did pop up a message about not being able to contact the gnome shell extensions site.)

Is there any benefit to reporting this as a bug before I move on to resolve it?

Eventually I'll try disabling shell extensions and next configuration files. At worst I'll have a go with XFCE and at worst, nuke and repave.

If I should file a bug, what's the best way (considering I cannot run any GUI programs.)

If it helps, I've captured a bit of /var/log/syslog that may reflect the issue and put at https://pastebin.com/UwdegT7Q. The salient line might be:

```
Jun  4 08:47:34 karakum gnome-shell[6106]: Connection to xwayland lost
```

Thanks!

Edit:
Extensions I *had* installed were

```
hbarta@karakum:~/Downloads$ ls -l extensions
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:28 alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 31 21:08 alt-tab-workspace@kwalo.net
drwxrwxr-x 4 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:34 custom-hot-corners@janrunx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 hbarta hbarta 4096 Mar 27 07:45 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 hbarta hbarta 4096 Feb  4 15:20 multi-monitors-add-on@spin83
drwxrwxr-x 4 hbarta hbarta 4096 Feb  4 15:21 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:29 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 30 19:23 workspace-labels@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 30 19:20 workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails@sustmidown.centrum.cz
hbarta@karakum:~/Downloads$
```

Moving all of them to a different location has resolved the issue.

Comment: dash to dock is not shipped with ubuntu. I don't know why you expect anything that isn't shipped with both the prior version nor the post-upgrade version of ubuntu to work. You did not follow the upgrade instructions to uninstall all peripheral software and reinstall after the upgrade. given ubuntu 19.04 released in april and dash-to-dock's last update was in march you can pretty much deduce 19.04 support is not a thing for dash-to-dock.

Comment: You probably have a GNOME extension conflict. `Dash to Dock` is known to have problems in 19.04. There are others too. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and I'll take a look for you. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @tatsu - dash to dock is in the universe repo. I guess that's not an endorsement that it is stable. That's too bad as it is a useful extension. (I had installed it from the web page but installing from the repo produced similar results.)

Yes, I did not follow the instructions. I upgraded using the GUI and must have overlooked that (or didn't realize it included Gnome Shell Extensions.) I install as much S/W as I can from the repos and don't consider it "third party."

Comment: @heynnema you can see the extensions I had installed and dash to dock was definitely a problem. I guess I would need to add them back one at a time to see which ones work.

thanks both for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You probably have a GNOME extension conflict.**

- dash-to-dock is known to have problems in 19.04.
- workspace-indicator has a problem.
- Why two alt-tab extensions?

$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:28 alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 31 21:08 alt-tab-workspace@kwalo.net
drwxrwxr-x 4 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:34 custom-hot-corners@janrunx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 hbarta hbarta 4096 Mar 27 07:45 dash-to-dock@micxgx.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 5 hbarta hbarta 4096 Feb  4 15:20 multi-monitors-add-on@spin83
drwxrwxr-x 4 hbarta hbarta 4096 Feb  4 15:21 window-list@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Apr 13 10:29 workspace-indicator@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 30 19:23 workspace-labels@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 2 hbarta hbarta 4096 Jan 30 19:20 workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails@sustmidown.centrum.cz
```

Add them back one at a time to see which ones work. Restart gnome-shell between changes.

Comment: One of the <alt><Tab> extensions was disabled.